# Is there something like postgis for mariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

Someone told me that [PostGIS](http://postgis.net) exists. Currently I'm storing latitude and longitude information un a MariaDB, but I want to know if there is something similar for MariaDB.

Unfortunately, migrating to PostgreSQL is not an option.

Comment: Could you use the spatial extensions for MySQL?

Comment: It looks like there is some support see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/gis-functionality/

Comment: There is, but it doesn't have anything like the functionality of Postgis. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743632/gis-postgis-postgresql-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server/22576304#22576304) explains some of that. But there is basic contains and intersects type functionality and storage/indexing of spatial types.

Comment: Maria DB has limited functionality for spatial data compering to PostGIS. What functionality would like to use?